# Run time error -2147467259(80004005) for using ADODB.Connection

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm trying to connect VBA to sql server f. I'm using Windows server 2016 data center and sql sever management studio V17.3 . So I used following objects in my VBA reference [image]

While I'm trying to execute below line

```
 Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
```

I'm getting error message

```
 Run time error -2147467259(80004005)
 Automation error,Unspecified error
```

Can you guide me to resolve this error

Answer (score 2):

Your ADO version is old (ADO 2.8 was included in Windows XP and Windows Server 2003). The next version is ADO 6 and "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library" is the newest.

It should be installed already on your computer, so just scroll down and mark that reference instead:

[image: Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library]

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub GetData()

Dim cnDump As ADODB.Connection
Set cnDump = New ADODB.Connection

' Provide the connection string.
Dim strConn As String

'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Data Source=XXXX\XXXX;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;Workstation ID=XXXX;Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False;"

'Now open the connection.
cnDump.Open strConn
```

Comment: Thank you for the code.But I'm getting error message in first line ,Dim cnDump As ADODB.Connection, same as the error message I mentioned in in my initial post.Do I need to add any addition object in my Reference?

Comment: No need to add any addition object in References. You just use connection using NEW keyword "Dim Cn As NEW ADODB.Connection".

Comment: ,Yes, after doing "Dim Cn As NEW ADODB.Connection that error is no longer coming.my connection statement is also executed.I used following statement to execute connection `conn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"`
Now I defined `Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset    Set rs = conn.Execute(SQLStr) ` but here again I'm getting error message `Run time error '-2147217865' automation error`. I'm using office 64 bit. Can you guide me to resolve this error?

Comment: sorry, but i have no more idea.

Comment: @Sonia Were you able to fix this?

Comment: No @ChipsLetten